# I am using linkify to parse the strings. Now there is a string "10 is < 20" . linkify creates a link out of this one too that i dont want. Any fix?

Tags: javascript, parsing, linkify

In my project I am using linkify so that it can convert all the incoming strings into link. But in doing this I am facing a case where incoming string is wrongly linkified.  This string "10 years < 20 years" is converted to `10 years <years>`. Is there a way in library where this can be prevented

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is fixed by Linkify - can not reproduce.